# prefetch limited number of related objects in django

Tags: python, database, django, orm

I want to display list of Posts with 5 latest Comments for each of them. How do I do that with minimum number of db queries?

```
Post.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('comment_set')
```

retrieves all comments while I need only few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with two queries. First get posts:

```
posts = list(Post.objects.filter(...))
```

Now run raw SQL query with `UNION` (NOTE: omitted ordering for simplicity):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=%s LIMIT 5"
query = []
for post in posts:
    query.append( sql % post.id )
query = " UNION ".join(query)
```

and run it:

```
comments = Comments.objects.raw(query)
```

After that you can loop over comments and group them on the Python side.

I haven't tried it, but it looks ok.

There are other possible solutions for your problem (possibly getting down to one query), have a look at this:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: followed the link you provided and found there another link which states that using unions is better in terms of performance. So the answer is accepted, thanks)